# Netbeans IDE did work after installation, but doesn't start after restart.

Tags: openjdk, netbeans

i installed Netbeans on Ubuntu 11.10 following these instructions: http://pasindudps.blogspot.com/2011/10/installing-netbeans-ide-in-ubuntu-1110.html.

It worked perfectly fine (creating projects, open projects, compile, run...) but after restarting netbeans started normally and it is shown as a running application in unity-panel but I can't access the programm.

I uninstalled and reinstalled it, it worked once but failed after restart.

Has anyone an idea what might be the problem here?

Thanks in advance. 
Regards

Comment: Possible permission problem, what happens when you run from terminal might show you an error?

Comment: Adding information to the previous comment: open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T), type `cd netbeans*/bin`, then type `./start` and check for any useful message. Maybe netbeans runs correctly but starts minimized for some reason, maybe it's a java-related problem (you can check your java version by running in a terminal: `java -version`)

Comment: thanks for you help. i tried to run netbeans from terminal, no errors occured. it started normally, is shown as active programm in unity-starter but i can't access it. 
java version is 1.6.0_23.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I did sudo su and then ran netbeans. It worked so it must be some config for my normal user

Answer (score 5):

I changed

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk"
```

to

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64"
```

in **netbeans-7.1/etc/netbans.conf** on **Ubuntu 12.04**

It worked.

Comment: didn't work either. tried every jdk i've installed. but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Install from software center, and tell us if is it working.
Always you can, install preferably from software center =)

Comment: Netbeans is not present in the 11.x repositories (anymore?). My bet would be the fact that Oracle is sponsoring the project. It's a true shame, since Netbeans is relatively superior compared to Eclipse in terms of stability & performance, deployment, and ease of use.

Comment: Very sorry for my answer, I'm in ubuntu 12.04 and it is present and I figured that will be present in 11.10.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, especially if Netbeans is present in 12.04! That's some good news here! :) I did explicitely mention Ubuntu 11.x in my comment however, because I haven't taken a look at Ubuntu 12.04 yet.

Comment: oh, I encourage you to try ubuntu 12.04, is still in beta, but it's stable enough for me

Comment: I'm impatient, but I do want to wait for the final release. I can't take the risk of running into bugs while working. :)